# How to get the image size on controllers, in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model that has an avatar as an attachment. Like this:

```
#user.rb
  attachment :avatar, type: :image
```

Im updating this image on my view, and calling a method on my controller. I put a logger debug to check the parameters that are going into my controller.

```
def update_profile
   logger.debug("******** Im updating update_profile with #{:params}")
```

And so, on my output I got:

```
Processing by ProfilesController#update_profile as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RPTztPwpRRFCmyaKytJuo2USQHFWxFUpr/9KKvM80CamgfJOs9tIVGl7LFVMcAxc+R8FnxdWqgAI4gP5wBV41Q==", 

"user"=>{"avatar"=>"{\"id\":\"35c47de458393c007951857e5fe1296c444b40c6ee1144e39342136b84e9\",\"filename\":\"Captura de Tela 2018-11-30 às 14.52.11.png\",\"content_type\":\"image/png\",\"size\":508316}"}}
```

I have a business rule that only Landscapes pictures should be on avatar. So, how can I check the height and weight of this picture on my controller?

Comment: What are you using to add attachments to your model? paperclip? carrierwave? activestorage?

Comment: Im using Refile

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541978/get-image-dimensions-using-refile